# How do you convert a hex string to a Date?

Tags: javascript, datetime, ethereum, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I've got a hex string, 0x63a4b534, I'd like to convert to a human readable date. However, I'm not sure how to do that. I've tried:

```
new Date("0x63a4b534").toLocaleDateString()
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// eth timestamp is in seconds. this will give you seconds
const timeInSeconds=parseInt('0x63a4b534',16)
// convert to miliseconds
const timeInMiliseconds=timeInSeconds*1000
const currentTime=new Date(timeInMiliseconds).toLocaleDateString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer and was close. https://stackoverflow.com/a/847196/15018688 
`new Date("0x63a4b534".toNumber() * 1000).toLocaleDateString()`

Comment: you will need to do a `parseInt(hex, 16)` or `Number(hex)`

Comment: @cmgchess that also works, without needing the `ethers.js` library I should mention